# Calling phone number in flutter application without re-directing to default phone dailler with permission request

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing an application using flutter one of my application features is calling phone numbers directly without re-directing to phone dailler and this feature is very fundamental to the app.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried? please post the code you are having troubles with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :- flutter_phone_direct_caller plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller

Comment: Thank you ☺️, this is what was looking it works for me I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Mark this as a write answer if this ans solved your problem. Upvoting will also be appreciated.(I'm new)